# Bookmark bar not go correctly position

Tags: bookmarks

I try to create a bookmark bar by using `\usepackage{bookmark}`
Here is my code

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{zref-savepos,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%package for loading images
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%-----------------
\usepackage{bookmark}

%---------------REF----------
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
%------------------

%fancy 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LH]{Restaurant Management Software}
\fancyhead[RH]{October 2020}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LF]{Nguyen Duy Anh}
\fancyfoot[CF]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[RF]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{1cm}

\addtolength\headwidth{2\FHoffset}

\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}

%-----------------------
%activate the style:

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
%border for title
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
%---------------------------------------
%bibligographies
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf {ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}}
 \chapter*{\LARGE ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf {LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}}
\chapter*{\LARGE LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf {LIST OF FIGURES}}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf {TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf {ABSTRACT}}
\vspace{15pt}
\begin{center} 
 \textbf{\large ABSTRACT}\\

\end{center}
\newpage

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\input{chapter/Introduction}

\chapter{DESIGN AND ANALYSIS}
\input{chapter/Materials}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY}
\input{chapter/Methodelogy}

\chapter{RESULT}
\input{chapter/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION AND FUTURE WORKS}
\input{chapter/Conclusion}

\nocite{one}
\nocite{two}
\nocite{three}
\nocite{four}
\nocite{five}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{REFERENCES}}
\printbibliography[title={REFERENCES}]

\chapter{APPENDIX}
\input{chapter/appendix}

\end{document}
```

When I download this file as PDF, then open it, it successfully creates the bookmark bar but the position of each chapter is not correct when I click on it.
Could someone help me find out what is wrong here?

Comment: After adding '\bookmarksetup{startatroot} ' the charter I input from file go correctly but the ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS, LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS..., ABSTRACT does not go correctly.

Comment: most of your \addcontentsline commands are in the wrong place, they point to the page before. Move them after the \chapter commands. Or use `\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline .... `